# Does Tomcat 7 support MDB listeners?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

Does Tomcat 7 has the EJB implementation to allow create queues and deploy MDB listeners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It only implements the JSP/Servlet API out the box ([JSR-245](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) and [JSR-315](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html)).

You can however use [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/tomcat.html) to enrich Tomcat with (limited) EJB support, including MDBs.

Comment: Is it possible to create queues in tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

No, Tomcat is a servlet container, not a complete Java EE server, it has no EJB support on board.

There's a rich choice of open/free full Java EE servers available, check out [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/), [Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) or [Jonas](http://wiki.jonas.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome).  And I'm probably forgetting several others.